# Links not clickable when not block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a html list containing links. For some reason when the list items are set to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` the links are not clickable and the hover states on the list items don't work. Only when the list items are set to `display:block` are the links clickable and the hover states work.

This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tovly/y2njdzkw/3/) demonstrating the problem.

This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tovly/zav4hwmy/) with the list items set to block and the links are clickable.

How can I set the list items to `display:inline` and still have them function?

Comment: which links are you talking about?

Comment: @jmore009 I'm talking about the links within the list items labeled as "All work", "Photos", "Programming", etc. This is one of them `<a class='filter-link' href='#' data-filter='.photos' id='.photos'>`

Comment: what browser are you using? they're working fine in the first fiddle you posted

Comment: @jmore009 I just tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer and it's not clickable and the hover state is not activating.

Comment: fiddle breaks due to missing scripts. Inspect in browser console, likely something covering them or a z-index issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have solved your problem. (Though I must admit absolutely no wordpress experience, strictly HTML, CSS & Javascript.) In your html you are experiencing an issue with stack order and one element is obscuring another. You have the header set to too large of a height and it's blocking the top portion of your main site content, which is why the links are not clickable until they cascade below the header section. `display:block` or `display: inline-block` have nothing to do with the clickability of  tags (to my knowledge).

The current code is:
    `<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="height:140px">`

Change the 140 to 67 like so:
    `<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="height:67px">`

I hope that works for you! :)

Comment: You're very welcome! If you ever have any other HTML or CSS questions, feel free to message me. Good luck on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see a problem but this sounds like a collapsed margins issue. Try setting your `a` tags to `display: block` and then set their parent `li`s to `display: inline-block`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2njdzkw/4/)

Comment: Setting the `<a>` tags to `display: block` allows the `li`s to be set to `display:inline` but they still stop functioning when the `li`s are set to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: The links and list items don't seem to be working in the fiddle you posted. They don't animate on hover and clicking them doesn't do anything. Here is a video showing what I mean: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5OxMCWiLhrMM24xSFI2eEJnMVU/edit?usp=drivesdk